# Fat 32 partition recognized by Linux not by OS X why?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems

I used Gparted to create 3 partitions on an unencrypted external 2 GB hard drive:

1. A FAT32 system (0x0c).
2. A Ext4 system with Linux installed on (I did this after creating the partitions).
3. A HFS system with a backup of OS X.

The HFS partition gets detected, the other 2 don't. I find it strange -- and frustrating -- that the FAT32 file system doesn't get detected by OS X but it does get detected by the newest version of Ubuntu. Why is this and how can I fix this?

**What I have tried**

I can't click the repair disk button in Disk Utility. I also can't mount it with the `mount` command (or was it an option of `fdisk`? I forgot), I also can't mount it with `DiskUtil MountDisk`.

When I do

```
sudo fsck_msdos -fy /dev/disk2s1
```

I get

```
** /dev/rdisk2s1
Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: 483001
```

^ note: this is OS X, apparently Ubuntu is more robust?

I also tried a normal `fsck` to no avail it just `fsck`s my normal hard drive and I can't mount the FAT32 partition, so I don't know how to `fsck` that.

I wouldn't want to format my HD unless I really have to.

Edit: I noticed that when I formatted the Linux installation (it was a clean install) to FAT32 on DiskUtility, then the filesystem type id is `0x0b` and not `0x0c`. When I searched a bit I saw that this is an older form of FAT32? Anyways, resetting the filesystem type id to `0x0b` (from `0x0c`) didn't work.

Comment: Why; Because Apple is friend-enemies with Microsoft

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100400/how-do-i-recover-an-invisible-os-x-boot-option-in-bootcamp-running-on-a-2013